# Using Node.js at a multicore system

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cluster-computing, multicore

I have been working on a game created with nodejs and socket.io. At this point I want to reduce the CPU overload so I tried to use cluster in my application.But with cluster I found out that I was creating more than one instance of my application and that  instances don´t share the same memory. The result was, with cluster players that are connected to different workers don´t see each other. What I really want is to improve the performance of my current game room and not creating more rooms which means cluster won´t work for me. Is there any other solution to improve my CPU performance without having to use cluster?
I was thinking for example, when I have a heavy function I could pass it to other CPU core and that CPU would make the calculation but how I do this? I need to share all variables/memory between both cores and I am not able to do that with cluster.

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: What about using `cluster` with something like redis to send/broadcast events/messages between the cluster workers?

Comment: I used redis because of socket.io but I can´t share all variables between different cores.

Comment: Why do you *need* to share variables?

Comment: Does anyone know if other games like agar.io handle 300-400 player per room with only one core?

Comment: I need to share variables because If i don´t I am creating another independent game room where no data is shared with the other rooms. What I really want is to speedup only one room.